# Thévenin's Theorem Example

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, current-source, thevenin

I just started learning Thévenin's Theorem. My textbook gives the following example:

[image]
[image]

I'm referring to online sources such as [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_7.html) to complete this problem. However, all of the circuit diagram examples that I find online are highly similar and unlike the textbook example.

Using my naive understanding, I removed the 4 kilo-ohm resistor and shorted out the 20V and 0.7V (diode) voltage sources. We then have  6 kilo-ohm resistor and 4.9 kilo-ohm resistor in series. Calculating the equivalent resistance, we get $$\frac{(6 k \Omega) (4.9 k \Omega)}{6 k \Omega + 4.9 k \Omega} \approx 2.7 k \Omega$$

But I suspect that I'm doing this incorrectly.

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this example.

EDIT: I misread the source material, which uses a *parallel* circuit as an example. Since we have a *series* circuit, the equivalent resistance would be $$6 k \Omega + 4.9 k \Omega = 10.9 k \Omega$$

Comment: @jsotola What in particular?

Comment: upvote for not walking away right after posting the question

Comment: Hint: completely disconnect the 4.9k resistor and calculate the Thevenin Equivalent for the voltage source and the two resistors 6k & 4k.  Then re-connect that equivalent circuit to the 4k9 resistor / diode combination and do your calculations.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks. Are you saying that I should be simply summing the resistances to find the equivalent resistance? The calculation I did was copied from the specified source. (see https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_7.html) EDIT: Oh, wait, that calculation is for resistors in *parallel*, not series.

Comment: @DwayneReid thanks for the hint. Why do we disconnect the 4.9k one instead of the 4k one?

Comment: @ThePointer, you can do it either way. Main point: Get the Thevenin equivalent for the 20 V source plus the resistors, either just the 6k and 4k, or all three of them. Probably your solution falls out quickest if you merge all 3 into the thevenin circuit.

Comment: @ThePointer, you said that you have two resistors in series and then you included an equation for parallel resistors ...... so either you have two resistors in parallel or you used the wrong formula ..... start by confirming how the resistors are connected in the Thévenin equivalent circuit

Comment: @jsotola Yes you're right, I misread the source material.

Comment: @ThePhoton ok, thanks. How do I go about merging all 3 into a Thévenin circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just learning about Thevenin, it's probably easiest to see things in the following way:

1. Notice that the \$6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor and the \$4\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor span between two voltage sources (at \$0\:\text{V}\$ and \$20\:\text{V}\$.)
2. Convert that pair of resistors and voltage sources to their Thevenin equivalent (which will be a new voltage source and a series resistance.)
3. Now you should have a Thevenin voltage, \$V_\text{TH}\$, followed by its Thevenin resistance, \$R_\text{TH}\$, followed by a \$4.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor (in series), followed by the diode.
4. Since you know the diode drop (given to you, a priori), you just subtract it from the Thevenin voltage value. This will be the remaining voltage that is across the remaining Thevenin resistance in series with the \$4.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor.
5. The problem is now reduced to \$I_D=\frac{V_\text{TH}-V_D}{R_\text{TH}+4.9\:\text{k}\Omega}\$.

That's all there is to it.

The primary insight is recognizing step (1) above. Those two resistors and their voltage sources can be converted readily into \$V_\text{TH}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}\$. The rest is just basic machinery steps.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit will simplify to the following:

Disconnect R2 from the power source voltage divider.  Calculate Vth and Rth.  These are easy to calculate.

Now you have a voltage source with two resistors in series feeding a diode.  Calculate the total current.  Use that current to calculate the voltage across R2.

Takes only a minute or two, total.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please explain how this works. I am unsure of how to do the necessary calculations.