# simple circuit analysis kcl kvl

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

can i know what, why and how this **Rth** is parallel / how its calculated?

answer by jonk: thevenin analysis

---

**i mean my solution would be:**

> I1 = I2+ I

.

> I1 = (9-V2)/10k
>   I2 = V2/20k
>   I = V2-0.7/20k

.

> I1 = I2+ I
>   (9-V2)/10k = V2/20k + V2-0.7/20k
>   (9-V2)/10k = (2*V2- 0.7)/20k
>   2*(9-V2) = (2*V2- 0.7)
>   **edit:**
>   V2 = 6.23v **// missed up here**
>   edit: V2 is actually 4.675v

**V = V2 - 0.7V = 5.53

i = 5.53/20k = 0.276mA**

this supposed to be example from a university lecture, what im missing here?

**Edit:**
how this nodal analysis is different than above thevenin analysis

Comment: I addressed a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/427892/38098). But it seems as though you may not be familiar with the process of forming a Thevenin equivalent circuit with one voltage source and one series impedance from a pair of voltage sources and a pair of impedances. Do you know how to turn a voltage source and a resistor divider into a thevenin voltage and a series resistance?

Comment: no, i just looked it up, my method above was nodal analysis i still don't see why they are different. i will check Thevenin and study to validate what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Thevenin

Let's start with a simple voltage divider. I'll use the name \$V_\text{CC}\$ for the name of a given voltage source for the divider, for lack of a better name. The point of the exercize is to replace the circuit on the left with an equivalent circuit on the right. This is the process of creating a Thevenin equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKtYNt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the above case, the right-hand side Thevenin equivalent is \$V_\text{TH}=V_\text{CC}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$.

So, now your circuit can be transformed using the above Thevenin idea (if you need a proof, there are plenty available on the web.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftwktA.png)</sup>

From the right side, you can compute the current as \$I=\frac{6\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{6.667\:\text{k}\Omega+20\:\text{k}\Omega}=198.75\:\mu\text{A}\$ (the diode voltage subtracts from the total voltage available, prior to dividing by the total series resistance) and the voltage at \$V\$ as being \$V=I\cdot 20\:\text{k}\Omega=3.975\:\text{V}\$. (\$V_\text{X}\$ would be \$700\:\text{mV}\$ above \$V\$, of course.)

As you can see, this appears to match the answer you presented at the outset.

### Nodal

Using nodal analysis I get:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V}{R_3}&= I_{D_1}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}+I_{D_1}&=\frac{9\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}\\\\
V_\text{X}&=V+V_{D_1}
\end{align*}$$

This is three equations and three unknowns. Given \$V_\text{CC}=9\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{D_1}=700\:\text{mV}\$ and your resistor values, this provides:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{D_1}&=198.75\:\mu\text{A}\\\\
V&=3.975\:\text{V}\\\\
V_\text{X}&=4.675\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

Same results as before.

Comment: thank you i found out i ve stupid algebra mistake

Comment: @Hasanalattar Oh! We all make such mistakes. No problem.